# JSON.parse() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, json

in my server (python/django) side,

I have an array like this:

```
comments = [['rwerw', '215', '/news/215/'], ['wrwerwer', '215', '/news/215/'], ['Woinfoqf', '215', '/news/215/'], ['Good', '215', '/news/215/'], ["He's good", '215', '/news/215/']]
```

which I pass through to my ajax call as a string:

```
...

return JsonResponse({'comments': str(comments)})
```

I then use `JSON.parse()` to turn it back into an array object.

```
console.log(data.comments); // logs the json
var comments = JSON.parse(data.comments); // error
```

However for some reason `JSON.parse()` is not working. When I use it I get the following error:

Error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data
.success 
n.Callbacks/i 
n.Callbacks/j.fireWith 
z 
.send/c/<
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert the list of comments to string - let it be a list and let the `JSONResponse` properly dump the whole dictionary into JSON:

```
return JsonResponse({'comments': comments})
```